# Windows not in GRUB startup screen

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-xp, boot-repair

I recently used Boot Repair to fix GRUB startup, but now when I start my computer, Windows XP, my old OS, doesn't apppear. It shows Ubuntu, Ubuntu (recovery mode), memory test and a second memory test. There is also a subsection for previous Linux versions, but that only contains Ubuntu and its recovery. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post link to BootInfo report from Boot-Repair above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to detect your installed OSs again. Boot into your normal Ubuntu, open a terminal and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

That should detect all installed operating systems and update your `grub` accordingly. Windows should be there next time you reboot, as long as you see a line similar to this in the output:

```
Found Windows XP (loader) on /dev/sda2
```